# open source Todo (list-type) app - that is synchronized across devices?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to find an open source list app that is synchronized across devices for android.  What I mean is that if person A and person B have a shared list, that when person B ticks something off, person A's list also updates.

I am looking for an open source app so that I can learn how something like this can be done through an example.  However I would also be happy with a tutorial that covers the list creation and synchronization...

I know that this question may annoy some people, but I decided to post it because a solid example/tutorial would really help me to avoid posting 50 questions a day to this forum.

Thanks

Comment: It's not that the question "annoys people", it's that it's specifically and explicitly off-topic.

Comment: where should this be posted then?

Answer (score 1):

Use the meteor todo (google it)app along with cordova. It will have the same server and thus will be synchronized. I believe it is what you require, check it out

PS: Dude are you really stack agnostic? Btw meteor is awesome, so it would be a cool choice

Answer (score 1):

this question is really inappropriate but I will try to help you.

First of all, look at this tutorial to learn how to use Parse.com to save and retrieve data from server.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-Data-driven-Apps-with-Parse

Now, check this tutorial to learn how to list data with RecyclerView:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Hope that helps.